# Module and classes handling (dynamic linking)

Tags: c++, windows

Run into a bit of an issue, and I'm looking for the best solution concept/theory.

I have a system that needs to use objects. Each object that the system uses has a known interface, likely implemented as an abstract class. The interfaces are known at build time, and will not change. The exact implementation to be used will vary and I have no idea ahead of time what module will be providing it. The only guarantee is that they will provide the interface. The class name and module (DLL) come from a config file or may be changed programmatically.

Now, I have all that set up at the moment using a relatively simple system, set up something like so (rewritten pseudo-code, just to show the basics):

```
struct ClassID
{
    Module * module;
    int number;
};

class Module
{
    HMODULE module;
    function<void * (int)> * createfunc;

    static Module * Load(String filename);

    IObject * CreateClass(int number)
    {
        return createfunc(number);
    }
};

class ModuleManager
{
    bool LoadModule(String filename);

    IObject * CreateClass(String classname)
    {
        ClassID class = AvailableClasses.find(classname);
        return class.module->CreateObject(class.number);
    }

    vector<Module*> LoadedModules;
    map<String, ClassID> AvailableClasses;
};
```

Modules have a few exported functions to give the number of classes they provide and the names/IDs of those, which are then stored. All classes derive from `IObject`, which has a virtual destructor, stores the source module and has some methods to get the class' ID, what interface it implements and such.

The only issue with this is each module has to be manually loaded somewhere (listed in the config file, at the moment). I would like to avoid doing this explicitly (outside of the `ModuleManager`, inside that I'm not really concerned as to how it's implemented).

I would like to have a similar system without having to handle loading the modules, just create an object and (once it's all set up) it magically appears.

I believe this is similar to what COM is intended to do, in some ways. I looked into the COM system briefly, but it appears to be overkill beyond belief. I only need the classes known within my system and don't need all the other features it handles, just implementations of interfaces coming from somewhere.

My other idea is to use the registry and keep a key with all the known/registered classes and their source modules and numbers, so I can just look them up and it will appear that `Manager::CreateClass` finds and makes the object magically. This seems like a viable solution, but I'm not sure if it's optimal or if I'm reinventing something.

So, after all that, my question is: How to handle this? Is there an existing technology, if not, how best to set it up myself? Are there any gotchas that I should be looking out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM very likely is what you want. It is very broad but you don't need to use all the functionality.  For example, you don't need to require participants to register GUIDs, you can define your own mechanism for creating instances of interfaces. There are a number of templates and other mechanisms to make it easy to create COM interfaces. What's more, since it is a standard, it is easy to document the requirements.

One very important thing to bear in mind is that importing/exporting C++ objects requires all participants to be using the same compiler. If you think that ever could be a problem to you then you should use COM.  If you are happy to accept that restriction then you can carry on as you are.

Comment: Some of the features COM offers, such as not worrying about compilers or runtimes and I believe allowing C# modules to be used are pretty nice, but I've yet to find any info on how I would go about making this work in COM. What I've been able to find on making new interfaces/objects involves a whole lot of defining and boilerplate code. Do you have any suggestions on good docs to look at?

Comment: I think I'd look at ATL for creating COM objects. I'd also read Don Box's book, Essential COM. Actually you only need the first couple of chapters. It's really not that scary!

Comment: The book has a good explanation of how things work, and some of the MSDN docs make for nice tutorials. Going to try this and see if it works out. Thanks for the suggestions. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if any technology exists to do this.

I do know that I worked with a system very similar to this. We used XML files to describe the various classes that different modules made available. Our equivalent of ModuleManager would parse the xml files to determine what to create for the user at run time based on the class name they provided and the configuration of the system. (Requesting an object that implemented interface 'I' could give back any of objects 'A', 'B' or 'C' depending on how the system was configured.)

The big gotcha we found was that the system was very brittle and at times hard to debug/understand. Just reading through the code, it was often near impossible to see what concrete class was being instantiated. We also found that maintaining the XML created more bugs and overhead than expected.

If I was to do this again, I would keep the design pattern of exposing classes from DLL's through interfaces, but I would not try to build a central registry of classes, nor would I derive everything from a base class such as IObject.

I would instead make each module responsible for exposing its own factory functions(s) to instantiate objects.

Comment: In my current setup, each module exports 3 functions (`int ClassCount()`, `const char * ClassInfo(int)` and `IObject * ClassCreate(int)`). That provides an easy way to avoid the XML definitions you describe and provides the factory built in, sort of. The `IObject` base just guarantees all objects know what they are and where they came from.

Comment: I didn't like the common base class in our system because it lead to a huge number of dynamic_cast statements in the code. As in your example, we returned all objects as IObject* and then casted to the correct interface. I prefer to have factory functions return meaningful interfaces, even if that means I need multiple functions. That said, this certainly doesn't prevent you from using a common base class if you need to know where objects come from.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean and how it could have some benefits. How did you handle knowing what objects were available (by name) overall, though?

Comment: We essentially did exactly what you have described above. The XML needed to record the class name so that the manager knew which dll to ask for it in. This same class name would appear in a case statement in the the DLL CreateObject function. Finally the person using the DLL needed to know this classname to request it from the manager. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Quite nicely, thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to handle this.